# selecting array element using unique id not working in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

My application has "Posts" which will have stories

Now I want to select one post and only one of its stories from multiple stories in the story array

```
var db = req.db;
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var collection = db.get('clnPost');
var userId = req.body.userId;
var postId = req.body.postId;
var storyId = req.body.storyId;
var ObjectID = mongo.ObjectID;
 var mongo = require('mongodb');
var ObjectID = mongo.ObjectID;
collection.find({ _id: ObjectId(postId), "Stories._id": ObjectID(req.body.storyId)}, function (e, docs) {
//some processing on the docs
}
```

I want this to return the post along with only story which has the story Id that is sent through the request, but its returning all the stories in the stories array

[image]

Here I am getting all the stories for that post, where as  i need only the story with Id that matches `req.body.storyId`

I also tried using **$elemMatch** after checking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection) but still got the same results

```
collection.find({ _id: postId}, {Stories: { $elemMatch: { _id: req.body.storyId } } }, function (e, docs) {
```

I also tried

```
collection.find({ "Stories._id":ObjectID(storyId)}, {"Stories.$":1,Stories: {$elemMatch: { "Stories._id" :ObjectID(storyId) }} } , function (e, docs) {
```

The structure of the post document is as follows

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "55a7847ee4b07e03cc6acd21"
    },

    "Stories": [
        {
            "userId": "743439369097985",
            "story": "some story goes on here",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "55c0b9367d1619a81daaefa0"
            },
            "Views": 29,
            "Likes": []
        },
        {
            "userId": "743439369097985",
            "story": "some story goes on here",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "55c0bbd97abf0b941aafa169"
            },
            "Views": 23,
            "Likes": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I also tried using **$unwind**

```
 var test= collection.aggregate( //where collection =db.get('clnPost')
            { $match: { "Stories._id": ObjectID(storyId) } },
            { $project : { Stories : 1 } },
            { $unwind : "$Stories" }
            );
```

Update 1: i am using monk and hence aggregate is not working

Comment: okay will attach screenshot in a while pls hold on

Comment: plz no screenshots. It is not that hard to copy a normal text document, but it will be easy to use it.

Comment: added both screenshot and plain text

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: @BlakesSeven I have already tried using the $elemmatch as suggested in one of the answers, but still i am getting all the stories, not sure what i am missing

Comment: @vignesh Then you are using different code to what you are posting, If anything I would supect your code to return "nothing" since `req.body.storyId` would be a string and you are trying to match to an `ObjectId`. The linked answer(s) contain examples or all possiblities, singular match and multiple matches. Follow them. And make sure to cast to the correct type.

Comment: yes Blake I tried using ObjectID(storyId), it returned the parent (post) with all the stories

Comment: @BlakesSeven  I have updated my code in question pls check

Answer (score 2):

I can not copy your example document, so I used similar one:

```
{
    "_id" : "55a7847ee4b07e03cc6acd21",
    "Stories" : [{
        "userId" : "743439369097985",
        "story" : "some story goes on here",
        "_id" : "55c0b9367d1619a81daaefa0",
        "Views" : 29,
        "Likes" : [ ]
    }, {
        "userId" : "743439369097985",
        "story" : "some story goes on here",
        "_id" : "55c0bbd97abf0b941aafa169",
        "Views" : 23,
        "Likes" : [ ]
    }]
}
```

To get what you want, you need to use [dollar projection operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#usage-requirements) in a way I used it here.

```
db.collection.find({
   "Stories._id": "55c0bbd97abf0b941aafa169"
}, {
   "Stories.$": 1
}).pretty()
```

Comment: its is bringing the parent post with all stories attached to it 
anyway to bring only one story which has this id?

Comment: In the result set, i am getting post with all stories in it. I need to bring the post with only one story which has storyId=ObjectId(storyId).
i.e if the post contains 10 stories, i want to fetch only one particular story which has that story id

Comment: @vignesh if you will insert the document that I copied and use my query, you will se only one story.

Comment: i have updated my code in the question please check if there are any mistakes